# I am trying to add rating to a user and running in to error Call to a member function Review() on null. in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

i am trying to add rating and reviews to the user here is so far what i have done 
i have made a separate controller for review 
and in the store method of that controller my code is as follow

```
public function store(Request $request,User $user)
   {
       //
       $up=User::find($user->id);
       if($request->review)
       {
           $up->Review()->attach($request->review);
       }
     if($request->rating)
     {
         $up->Review()->attach($request->rating);
     }
       return redirect()->back();

   }
```

i have created a seprate model for the review as well in which my code is looks like this

```
class Review extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable=['rating','review'];
    Public function User()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

where in my user model i have made this

```
  Public function Review()
      {

          return $this->belongsToMany(Review::class);
      }
```

where as my migrations looks like this

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('review_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('rating');
            $table->string('review');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my forms looks like this

```
<form action="{{route('ReviewsUser',$user->id)}}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')




                            <div class="feedback-yes-no">
                                <strong>Your Rating</strong>
                                <div class="leave-rating">
                                    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-1" value="1" checked/>
                                    <label for="rating-1" class="icon-material-outline-star"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-2" value="2"/>
                                    <label for="rating-2" class="icon-material-outline-star"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-3" value="3"/>
                                    <label for="rating-3" class="icon-material-outline-star"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-4" value="4"/>
                                    <label for="rating-4" class="icon-material-outline-star"></label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-5" value="5"/>
                                    <label for="rating-5" class="icon-material-outline-star"></label>
                                </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>

                            <textarea class="with-border" placeholder="Enter Your Comments" name="review" id="review" cols="7" required></textarea>



                        <!-- Button -->
                        <button class="button full-width button-sliding-icon ripple-effect" type="submit" >Your Review's <i class="icon-material-outline-arrow-right-alt"></i></button>
                    </form>
```

what i am trying to do is to store reviews that other users have given the user anyone who can help me overcome this error would be highly appreciated .

Comment: what about `$user->Review()->attach($request->review);`? and plz post the route code

Comment: not working Route::post('Reviews','ReviewsController@store')->name('ReviewsUser');

Comment: in your route, you don't bound the {user} parameter to the `User` model, so you cannot find the user in your store action

Comment: You're not passing your user model properly, what does your form look like?

Comment: i have edited the u can see form as well

Answer (score 0):

```
Call to a member function Review() on null
```

This error means that your variable `$up` calling the member function `Review()` has a null value. Which means it's not finding your user in

`$up = User::find($user->id);`

Your post route doesn't have a route parameter to pass the user ID to find the user in the first place.

Therefore, changing this

```
Route::post('Reviews','ReviewsController@store')->name('ReviewsUser');
```

to this

```
Route::post('Reviews/{user}','ReviewsController@store')->name('ReviewsUser');
```

will now capture the User ID in your controller via `User $user`

Comment: can u please suggest me how to add rating to user in laravel 5.8 i don't think i am doing it the right way att all any video tutorial u can share would be a great help..